# Loading Text File to Python and Converting its Binary values to Decimals With Their Signs

Tags: python, file, numpy

I am asked to load a text file which contains binary values representing to current and voltage, and decimals representing to time, The left-most digit of each binary values indicates the sign..after loading the text file I have to convert binaries to decimals including their signs ( 0> positive, 1>negative)

I have tried to use numpy to do this but I am not able to write it successfully.

```
import numpy as np   
data=open("rawdata.bin","r")
a=np.fromfile(data,dtype=float,count=-1)
```

Actually, I do not know how and what to do clearly ?

Comment: Your question cannot be answered with the information that you provide. Is it a text file or a binary file? If it is a text file, what does the contents look like?

Comment: Well, it is a text file actually but I have changed its format to bin since I thought it would be much easier with that way, here is the txt file which I am talking about..http://www.filedropper.com/rawdata

Comment: I think you should paste the first few lines of that file into your question, along with what you think the represented value should be. Also: are you sure that the left-most bit is a sign bit and not [One's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones'_complement)?